# How to use Collectors.groupingBy to have a HashMap values

Tags: java, java-stream

I've recently started learning Streams and Lambda Expressions and ran into a problem with my code.

I have a list of names that I want to group them by their length and their count for which I had to use Collectors.groupingBy() twice:

```
public class StreamApplicationDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>
              (Arrays.asList("Amir", "Hatef","Mehran", "Mojtaba",
                    "Mohammad", "Ali", "Davood", "Reza", "Mohsen"));


        Map<Integer, List<String>> groupByLengthMap = names.
            stream().
                collect(Collectors.groupingBy(name -> name.length()));
        System.out.println(groupByLengthMap);


        Map<Integer, Long> groupByLengthNumberMap = names.
                  stream().
                  collect(Collectors.groupingBy(name -> name.length(), 
        Collectors.counting()));
              System.out.println(groupByLengthNumberMap);


    }
}
```

Output:

```
 {3=[Ali], 4=[Amir, Reza], 5=[Hatef], 6=[Mehran, Davood, Mohsen], 7=[Mojtaba], 8= 
 [Mohammad]}
 {3=1, 4=2, 5=1, 6=3, 7=1, 8=1}
```

As You can see I used the Streams terminal method (Collect()) to group the names list by their length and then I had to group the list another time and map it by the length of the names and their numbers.
But I want to merge these two groupings and do like this:

{3{1 = [Ali]}, 4{2=[Amir, Reza]}...}

And as you can see I want to have a map that has the words length as the key and a map of the count of the words and a list of them as the value of that key:

Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List>>

But I don't know how I can do this only by using the Collect() and groupingBy() method which uses a function as input. Is it even possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *{3{1 = [Ali]}, 4{2=[Amir, Reza]}...}* Isn’t that a bad design? `List` has a `size` method, so it’s just redundant. For what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> names = List.of("Amir", "Hatef", "Mehran", "Mojtaba",
        "Mohammad", "Ali", "Davood", "Reza", "Mohsen");
    Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<String>>> result = names.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
            e -> Map.of(e.getValue().size(), e.getValue())));
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

output:

```
{3={1=[Ali]}, 4={2=[Amir, Reza]}, 5={1=[Hatef]}, 6={3=[Mehran, Davood, Mohsen]}, 7={1=[Mojtaba]}, 8={1=[Mohammad]}}
```